# Can't fetch all rows from a MySQL table

Tags: c++, mysql

I am new to using mysql in c++. I have a problem in retrieving data from my database. The database has 4 rows of data in a table, but when I try to retrieve the data, it shows only one row.

For example, I have a table `student` with a column `name`, where the values are
`"Jessy"`, `"Jessie"`, `"Jessica"`, and "`Jess`"

Below is the used code:

```
mysql_query(_mysqlCon, "select *from studentdatabase");
    _mysqlResult = mysql_store_result(_mysqlCon);
    while ((_mysqlRows = mysql_fetch_row(_mysqlResult))) {
        printf("%s\n", _mysqlRows[0]);
    }
```

When the code has been executed, I only receive one row, namely `"Jess"`.

When I try to get the number of rows from the database with the following code:

```
mysql_query(_mysqlCon, sqlStatement);
    _mysqlResult = mysql_store_result(_mysqlCon);
    return mysql_num_rows(_mysqlResult);
    mysql_free_result(_mysqlResult);
    mysql_close(_mysqlCon);
```

It returns the correct amount of 4. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem of my code?

Comment: Show declaration of `_mysqlResult` and `_mysqlRows`.

Comment: mysql_query(_mysqlCon, "select *from studentdatabase");add space between * and from as mysql_query(_mysqlCon, "select * from studentdatabase");

Comment: Check value of `mysql_errno(_mysqlCon)`

Comment: MYSQL_RES    *_mysqlResult;
MYSQL_ROW    _mysqlRows;
this is my declaration

Comment: i change my code to : mysql_query(_mysqlCon, "select * from studentdatabase");
but the result still the same